# How do I enforce assertions for Eiffel through command line?

Tags: shell, assertion, eiffel, enforcement

[Eiffel](http://eiffel.org) has a feature [Design by Contract](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET%3A%20Design%20by%20Contract%20%28tm%29%2C%20Assertions%20and%20Exceptions#exception_handling). According to this, for any routine, there is a check that assertions such as `require` and `ensure` must be true. However, I haven't been able to find out how to enforce the rule through command line that if the assertions are false, there must be an error/exception thrown by the compiler or during run time.

For example, if this is the root class,

```
class
    APPLICATION

inherit
    ARGUMENTS

create
    make

feature {NONE}


    object: TEST1
    make
            -- Run application.
        do          
            create object
            object.function(-1)
            print(object.value)
        end
end
```

and this is the `TEST1` class

```
class
    TEST1

feature

    value: INTEGER
            -- value for testing
    function(val: INTEGER)
            -- Assign
        require
            val>0
        do
            value:=val
        ensure
            value>0     
        end

end
```

The program compiles and executes without any error, even though both the assertions are violated.

I am compiling using

`ec application.e`

However, Eiffel Studio does report a violation of contract.

So, how can one enforce this through command line? Is there a particular flag to use?

Comment: Did you ever come across a solution for this?

Comment: @JatinSharma I am not very sure, you can try the answer below, or see if this helps: https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffelstudio/EiffelStudio-_Using_command_line_options

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GUI version of EiffelStudio and command-line version of EiffelStudio use different defaults when they create new projects: command-line version turns off assertion monitoring and GUI version turns on assertion monitoring. In fact you can open a project created with a command-line version in GUI, or, conversely, compile a project created in GUI version by a command-line compiler. The project settings are kept in a `.ecf` file and are part of a project, i.e. this `.ecf` file should be distributed together with the project.

To address the particular issue you describe, open the `.ecf` in GUI (*File | Open Project | Add Project | Open*), then navigate to *Project | Project Settings | Assertions*, turn on all assertions and press *Save*, exit from the GUI version. Now when you recompile your project from the command-line, the assertions will be turned on and you'll get an exception trace during execution as expected.

Comment: This is not working for me. The setting shows that all assertions are set to true, but still the program passes even when the assertion is violated when I run it using bash.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, Would you try to remove `EIFGENs` directory, preserving `application.ecf` at the top of the project and recompile from scratch?